# How many ways can 4 men and 4 women stand in a line so that the men are together and the women are together

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Question: How many ways can $\mathbf{4}$ men and $\mathbf{4}$ women line up with all the women together and all the men together?

My thoughts: I begin my solution to the problem by adding the total amount of men and women together: $\mathbf{8}$. With that in mind, I find how many ways the men can be lined up. The men can be lined up in $\mathbf{4!}$ ways, likewise the women can be lined up in $\mathbf{4!}$ ways. Thus, the product of these two groups lining up is $\mathbf{576}$.

This is where I can't really understand how the solution $\mathbf{1152}$ is met. Multiplying $\mathbf{576}$ $\cdot$ $\mathbf{2}$ gives me this value, but I don't understand why. What are your thoughts?

Comment: What if women would stand on the men shoulders (or vice versa)? (They are in a line and together)

Comment: I don't see the point of having hidden text in the question. I would remove it (i.e., make it visible) but I'm not sure others would agree.

Comment: The x2 part comes from who goes first. You can go 4! (women) x 4! (men), or 4! (men) x 4! (women). So 4!x4!x2 (it is actually 2! if you generalize)

Comment: What if they're on a *really* tiny planet #RickAndMorty, so tiny that the last person in line is actually right in front of the first person in line because they wrapped all the way around the *world*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The men can go first, or the women can go first. Two options means multiply by two.

For another example, what if there is one man and one woman? How many ways can they line up? Well $1!\times 1!\times 2!$

Comment: So, if there was a group for 4 dogs, would the same principle apply but x 3?

Comment: @LeSunstrike: Not 'x 3', but 'x 3!', i.e. 'x 6'. (The options are women-then-men-then-dogs, women-then-dogs-then-men, men-then-women-then-dogs, men-then-dogs-then-women, dogs-then-women-then-men, and dogs-then-men-then-women.)

Comment: Yes then there would be 3*2*1, 3 possible slots for first group, 2 for second and so on.

Comment: @ruakh So if there was a group for dogs. The first person could be chosen in 12 different, the fifth person in 8 different and the ninth person in 1 way making the solution: 12*3*2*1*8*3*2*1*4*3*2*1 = 82944?

Answer (score 8):

There are two groups. The groups can be arranged in $2!$ ways and there are 4 people in each group so each group can be arranged in $4! \times 4!$ ways. The total number of arrangements is $1152 = 4! \times 4! \times 2!$

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if you wrote, "There are two groups, which can be arranged in $2!$ ways."

Answer (score 6):

The first person can be chosen in $8$ ways. The next three persons can be chosen in $3$, $2$ and $1$ ways, respectively (they have to be the same sex as the first person). Then for the fifth person there are $4$ options again, and then $3$, $2$ and $1$ possibilities for the remaining $3$ persons. Therefore, the total number of ways is
$$
8 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 1152. \quad (=2 \times 4! \times 4!)
$$
The expression $2 \times 4! \times 4!$ can be explained by the fact that there are $2$ ways to decide the gender of the first person and that there are $4!$ ways to order the men and $4!$ ways to order the women.

Answer (score 1):

The group of men can be in front or in the back: $2$ possibilities

In the group of men, there are $4\times3\times2$ possible positions $= 24$

In the group of women, same number: $24$

So the answer is $2 x 24 x 24 = 1152$